# how do i run multiple select statements in oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written the following procedure

```
create or replace procedure sp_abc_profile 
(
  f_symbol_in abc.colname%TYPE
)
is profile abc%rowtype;
is profile2 abc2%rowtype;
begin
  SELECT fname, lname,mname,age
    INTO profile
  FROM abc
  WHERE f_symbol = f_symbol_in;

  SELECT initiaiinvestment AS minInitialInvestment, pr as qt, class1 as clss
    into profile2
  FROM 
      abc2 
  WHERE f_symbol = f_symbol_in;
end;
```

Upon executing the above I get error message as follows:

> Error(7,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>
> Error(21,5): PL/SQL:ORA-00913: too many values

I don't want to select all the rows in both tables.

How can I write multiple select statements in a procedure, so that every single select statement in procedure returns a resultset.

Comment: Which is the 7th and the 21th line in the code?

Comment: actually i changed the procedure's sql statements. The Posted error message belongs to the original procedure having more sql select statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions is to use CURSORS in oracle so that every single select statement in procedure returns a resultset.

That resultset can then be traversed in your preferred scripting language for desired output.

```
create or replace 
procedure sp_abc_profile
(
  symbol_in in tablename.fieldname%type,
  cursor1 out SYS_REFCURSOR,
  cursor2 out SYS_REFCURSOR,
)
as
begin


    open cursor1 for
         {your select statement here}


    open cursor2 for
        {your second select statement here}


end sp_abc_profile;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
is
profile abc.fname%type;
profile2 abc2.initiaiinvestment%type;
```

There is no problem with having multiple select statements in the procedure. It is about a mismatch of the selected columns and the PL/SQL type.

Beside that you seem to have too many `is` in your code.

For more info about using `select into`, check this link: [Oracle PL/SQL "select into" clause](http://dba-oracle.com/t_pl_sql_plsql_select_into_clause.htm)

Comment: I have multiple columns selected in few select statements under the procedure (edited my question) and I want to have them in one single variable. How is that possible.?

Comment: I don't want all the columns but only a few.

Comment: Check this link,  I also add it to the answer: http://dba-oracle.com/t_pl_sql_plsql_select_into_clause.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this we can have multiple select statement inside the procedure:

There was issue of too many value in your code.

```
create or replace procedure sp_abc_profile 
(
  f_symbol_in abc.colname%TYPE
)
is profile abc.fname%type;
is profile2 abc2.initiaiinvestment%type;
begin
  SELECT fname
    INTO profile
  FROM abc
  WHERE f_symbol = f_symbol_in;

  SELECT initiaiinvestment into profile2
  FROM 
      abc2 
  WHERE f_symbol = f_symbol_in;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out you have too many "is" statements.

When performing a select into a row variable, you need to select everything:

```
select *
into profile
from abc
where f_symbol = f_symbol_in;

select *
into profile2
from abc2
where f_symbol = f_symbol_in;
```

You are also running the risk of throwing an exception when you have multiple matches on f_symbol_in.  Your code could catch this exception, or you can restrict the number of rows (i.e. and rownum<=1) or alternatively look at collections to load all rows matching the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove redundant "IS"
2. Add: ROWNUM = 1

> ```
> create or replace procedure sp_abc_profile 
> (
>   f_symbol_in abc.colname%TYPE
> )
> is profile abc%rowtype;
> /*is*/ profile2 abc2%rowtype;
> begin
>   SELECT fname, lname,mname,age
>     INTO profile
>   FROM abc
>   WHERE f_symbol = f_symbol_in
>   AND ROWNUM = 1;
>
>   SELECT initiaiinvestment AS minInitialInvestment, pr as qt, class1 as clss
>     into profile2
>   FROM 
>       abc2 
>   WHERE f_symbol = f_symbol_in
>   AND ROWNUM = 1;
> end;
> ```